# Stop auto rotate after one rotation in onboarding flow for splash screens

Tags: swift

in my app there are 3 screens in the onboarding/splash screen flows which are set to auto rotate every 5 seconds

```
private var pageChangeTimer: Timer?
let pageChangeInterval: TimeInterval = 5.0
var pageChangeTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
        withTimeInterval: pageChangeInterval,
        repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
            self?.rotateScreen()
    }
```

how to stop auto rotate after one rotation of all three screens in onboarding flow for splash screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use timer's `invalidate()` instance method to stop it

```
var counter = 0

 pageChangeTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer( withTimeInterval: pageChangeInterval, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in 
    self?.rotateScreen() 
    self.counter += 1
    if self.counter == 3 {
    timer.invalidate()
 }
}
```